# Spring Data MongoDb - Manual Reference ObjectId to String

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Say I have a User class which has a manual reference to a customer document:

```
public class User(){
    @Id
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String customerId;
}
```

I want both the id & customerId to be stored as an ObjectId in mongo.

When saving a User document, the "id" gets converted to an ObjectId, however, the customerId gets saved as a string. I could have customerId of type ObjectId, but I would rather have the POJO as a string and have the customerId automatically convert to ObjectId when saving/querying. There does not seem to be any built in annotation which behaves like @Id, but can be used for manual references. How would I go about creating one, or is there a better solution? I have read a bit above converters, but I do not want to re-map the whole POJO to a DBObject.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when you get your customer data you have to create the objectId yourself.

`Db.Customer.find({"_id" : new ObjectId("$valueFromUserTable")});`

so in Spring Java you would:

```
ObjectId objId = new ObjectId("$valueFromUserTable");
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(objId));
Customer customer = super.mongoOps.find(query, Customer.class);
```